# How to hide all but the current index div / Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, multidimensional-array, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to selectively display a specific block of text when clicking on a map marker over google maps, while hiding all the other blocks. Since I am using the maps API, this needs to be vanilla javascript. A Jquery solution will not help. Please do not mark this as a duplicate of a question with only jquery solutions / answers. I reviewed those, I can find no way to transpose them into vanilla.

I have access to the ID's of the block which are set in the locations array. The blocks appear under the map, not as part of the map (they are not google maps tooltips). Both the markers and blocks come dynamically from a database, but for this purpose I'll make them static. On each instance there is a variable number of blocks + markers.

What I need to do is, .

The only solution I could think of was to retrieve the ID's of the previous and next index and hide those. However, that solution is flawed because 
- I get an error when i is 0 (as there is no previous element)
- the user might click randomly on the map so if he clicks on marker 2 then marker 4, both block2 and block 4 will be visible.

I need a way to set only the block corresponding with the marker clicked as visible, while setting all the others as invisible (when clicking the marker to set display:block to marker's corresponding block, and display:none to all the blocks associated with other markers).

Thank you very much!

HTML

```
<div id = "map"></div> <!--here is where the map will render with the pins set using google maps api -->
<div class="map-blocks">
 <div id="block1" style="display:none">Block 1</div>
 <div id="block2" style="display:none">Block 2</div>
 <div id="block3" style="display:none">Block 3</div>
 <div id="block4" style="display:none">Block 4</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    //define locations to be shown
var locations = [

    ['{{block1.name}}', {{block1.lat}}, {{block1.long}}, '{{block1.itemID}}', '{{block1.weight}}'],
    ['{{block2.name}}', {{block2.lat}}, {{block2.long}}, '{{block2.itemID}}', '{{block2.weight}}'],
    ['{{block3.name}}', {{block3.lat}}, {{block3.long}}, '{{block3.itemID}}', '{{block3.weight}}'],
    ['{{block4.name}}', {{block4.lat}}, {{block4.long}}, '{{block4.itemID}}', '{{block4.weight}}'],


];

//set the map attributes

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: {{zoom}},
    center: new google.maps.LatLng({{center-lat}},{{center-long}} ),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false
});

//set the market attributes

var markerIcon = {
    path: "M10,0.5c2.7-0.1,6.6,1.8,7.1,7c0.4,5.2-7.1,11.6-7.1,11.6l0,0c0,0-7.5-6.4-7.1-11.6C3.4,2.3,7.2,0.5,10,0.5",
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
    fillColor: "#094a72",
    fillOpacity: 0.8,
    scale: 2,
    strokeColor: '#094a72',
    strokeWeight: 1,
}

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var markerLabel = {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: '16px',
        text: locations[i][4],
    }
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        //url: locations[i][3],
        icon: markerIcon,
        label: markerLabel,
    });


// make the map center on the marker and display the correct article

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {

           var blockStatus = document.getElementById(locations[i][3]);
            var blockNext = document.getElementById(locations[i+1][3]);
            var blockPrevious = document.getElementById(locations[i-1][3]);    
           blockStatus.style.display = "block";
           blockNext.style.display = "none";
           blockPrevious.style.display = "none";
            map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        }
    })(marker, i));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```js
function showBlock(index) {
      // Get the div of the element to show. Use [index][3] for your own code.
  var blockStatus = document.getElementById('block' + index),
      // Get the block before the block of the clicked marker.
      previousBlock = blockStatus.previousElementSibling,
      // Get the block after the block of the clicked marker.
      nextBlock = blockStatus.nextElementSibling;

  // Make sure the block to show is visible.
  blockStatus.style.display = 'block';

  // Keep processing previous siblings until there is no more block 
  // before the current block.
  while (previousBlock !== null) {
       // Hide the block and...
       previousBlock.style.display = 'none';
       // try to get the block before this block.
       previousBlock = previousBlock.previousElementSibling;
  } 

  while (nextBlock !== null) {
       nextBlock.style.display = 'none';
       nextBlock = nextBlock.nextElementSibling;
  } 
}

// Change the visible block every second.
setInterval(function() {
  // Generate a random index, min = 1, max = 4.
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
  // Show the block for the generated index.
  showBlock(index);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="map-blocks">
 <div id="block1" style="display:none">Block 1</div>
 <div id="block2" style="display:none">Block 2</div>
 <div id="block3" style="display:none">Block 3</div>
 <div id="block4" style="display:none">Block 4</div>
</div>
```

This will work as long as the different blocks are all in the same parent container and no other elements are between them.

You could also go for a CSS based solution:

```js
var mapBlocks = document.querySelector('.map-blocks');

function showBlock(index) {
   // Get the div of the element to show. Use [index][3] for your own code.
  var blockStatus = document.getElementById('block' + index),
      // Get the currently visible block, we scope the querySelector to the element we know the blocks are in.
      visibleBlock = mapBlocks.querySelector('.is-visible');
  //querySelector returns null when there is no element matching the query. When visibleBlock is not null we have an element to manipulate.
  if (visibleBlock !== null) {
    // Remove the CSS class that makes the block visible.
    visibleBlock.classList.remove('is-visible');
  }
  
  // Assign the CSS class that makes the current block visible.
  blockStatus.classList.add('is-visible');;
}

// Change the visible block every second.
setInterval(function() {
  // Generate a random index, min = 1, max = 4.
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
  // Show the block for the generated index.
  showBlock(index);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.info-block {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .is-visible {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="map-blocks">
  <div id="block1" class="info-block">Block 1</div>
  <div id="block2" class="info-block">Block 2</div>
  <div id="block3" class="info-block">Block 3</div>
  <div id="block4" class="info-block">Block 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't solve problem no.2, which is that users will click on marker 1 then on a marker that's not next or previous such as marker 3 or 4 or n, because there can be a multitude of markers.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it will now process all the next and previous blocks of the block to show.

Comment: if I do that it will hide the current element as well, as the current element it's a sibling of the previous block.

Comment: I've updated my answer, with two working examples. One using the solution  with JS and another CSS based solution.

Comment: perfect, thank you, that worked. what was happening was that I did have some elements between injected by some other script. Thank you, you life saver!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to know I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a class to identify all targets.
2. Find you current block by id.
3. Loop through all block with `querySelectorAll`.
4. (Notice that you can `querySelectorAll` through a parent like with `CSS`).
5. Modify the style of all elements appropriately.

```js
function hideAllBut(n) {
  let target = document.getElementById('block' + n);
  document.querySelectorAll('.block')
    .forEach(function(block) {
      if (block === target) {
        block.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        block.style.display = "";
      }
    });
}
setTimeout(function(){hideAllBut(1)},1000);
setTimeout(function(){hideAllBut(2)},2000);
setTimeout(function(){hideAllBut(3)},3000);
setTimeout(function(){hideAllBut(4)},5000);
```

```css
.block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-blocks">
  <div class="block" id="block1">Block 1</div>
  <div class="block" id="block2">Block 2</div>
  <div class="block" id="block3">Block 3</div>
  <div class="block" id="block4">Block 4</div>
</div>
```